# How to make a list of mathematical notation?

Tags: glossaries

There are similar questions already, however it seems that the notation solutions (packages like glossaries and nomencl) only translate what a symbol means not actual notation that operates on symbols.

Imagined examples of what I can't do:

```
#G# - superversion of G
Ā - slightly improved A
```

Than in the text it would be used like: "[..] and you get #C# from [..]" where the reader should understand that the number signs act on "C" here.

To name a real and common example used in math - harpoon on top of a letter indicating it is a vector.

I don't see how this could be done with the standard packages. Is a manually made and maintained list the only way to go if I need at least one notation that can act on various things?

Comment: Do you mean something like the [`sample-fmt.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/samples/sample-fmt.tex) sample file that comes with `glossaries-extra`?

Comment: @NicolaTalbot It looks like what I need. So I have to define the operator as a command and then put it in `user1` for regular uses with `glsxtrfmt` and put `\mycommand{X}` in `symbol` for display in the list?

Comment: Yes. If you have any problems with it adjust `sample-fmt.tex` as appropriate and use it as a minimal example.